# Remove the diamond question mark from the echoed content of a UTF-8 RSS feed

Tags: php, xml, encoding, utf-8, rss

this is the header of all the RSS feeds I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and this is the encoding in my script

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

What I do is to display the content(description) of an RSS post using this `echo mb_substr($entry->description, 0, 490);`
but I have a diamond question mark at the end of some descriptions not all.

If I echo the whole description value, I don't get any question marks at the end. I have made a lot of researching and found nothing that works for me as a fix.
So, is there any possible working way to fix this or perhaps an alternative way to "cut" some of the echoed content?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indicate the encoding with:

```
mb_substr($entry->description, 0, 490, "UTF-8");
```

Otherwise, the `mbstring`  extension may assume a different encoding and treat the text in a fashion that corrupts the output.

Comment: Finally there is a person who actually knows how to fix this without extra functions or useless code. Thank you!